# Why can't I select an object in MSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, for-loop, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` named tasks.

That array is a collection of arrays which are called in a for loop.

In each of these arrays I am trying to call an object called 'name' but everytime I try this I get this error:

> -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c49ca0

and then the app is terminated.

Here is my code:

```
for (task in tasks) {
    NSLog(@"Task: %@", [[task objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"name"]);
}
```

The task and tasks array are set to NSMutableArray.

When I add:

```
NSLog(@"Task: %@", [task description]);
```

I get the array.

Where could I be going wrong?

Peter

Comment: Because what you have is not an NSMutableArray.  The above "unrecognized selector" message is clearly telling you it's an NSDictionary.

Comment: But I set it as 'NSMutableArray' at the top of the implementation file?

Comment: Okay, I added NSLog(@"@%", [task class]) and it turns out it is an NSDictionary. Thanks :)

Comment: @PeterStuart: The type of the variable does not affect the type of the object it points to. Just like assigning a `char*` to an `int*` doesn't transform the data being pointed to, assigning an object to the wrong type of variable just means you're lying to the type checker about what it is.

Comment: So by theory, I could make it  string but call it an array (although it's not)?

Comment: Got it working! I realized that it is an NSDirectionary and learned that valueForKey would work! Many Thanks!

Comment: Hint: In the latest versions of Objective-C (for maybe 18 months now) you can use C-style array notation with NSArrays and NSDictionarys:  `myArray[2]` or `myDictionary[@"myKey"]`.

Answer (score 3):

`task` in your code is a NSDictionary. It not responds to `objectAtIndex:`.

Probably you should change

```
NSLog(@"Task: %@", [[task objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"name"]);
```

to

```
NSLog(@"Task: %@", [task objectForKey:@"name"]);
```

or shorter:

```
NSLog(@"Task: %@", task[@"name"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, both of these suggestions leave errors: No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'objectForKey:' and Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSMutableArray *'

Comment: Add `NSLog([tasks description]);` before loop and `NSLog([task description]);` inside loop (first line), please. And add output to your question.

Comment: To look inside array you can use `NSLog(@"Task[0]: %@", [task[0] description]);`